# how to make a single parameter of function to take multiple different acceptable string values?

Tags: python, function, exception, parameters, parameter-passing

I am writing a function that processes data based on user input to the function parameter.

The user is limited to give only some case-sensitive acceptable inputs.

Please do check the function below and let me know if I am doing it the right way or is there any other better or pythonic way of doing it?

```
def test_func(param_1: str):
    acceptable_params = ['first', 'second', 'third']
    if param_1 not in acceptable_params:
        raise Exception(f'\'{param_1}\' is not an acceptable word')
    print(param_1)
```

This is working fine for me but I am curious if there is any better of doing this or making it look more professional?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this looks great for case sensitive checking, that's also sensitive to extra characters (like space or enter ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
assert param_1 in ['first', 'second', 'third'], f"'{param_1}' is not an acceptable word"
```